# .NET 5 Cryptographic Signatures exception Key does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, f#, cryptography, .net-5

I've implemented Digital Signature verification as per [msdn verifying-signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptographic-signatures#verifying-signatures)

Please don't let the fact it is in f# detract from the problem. I'm using the standard cryptography libraries from the .NET 5 framework

```ml
module GenericCryptography =
  let createRsa (res: GenericPublicKey) =
    let rsa = RSA.Create()

    // create params
    let mutable rsaParams = RSAParameters()
    rsaParams.Modulus <- res.Modulus
    rsaParams.Exponent <- res.Exponent

    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams)

    // export final RSA class
    rsa

  let rsaFormatter = 
    let r = RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa)
    r.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1") |> ignore
    r
  let rsaDeformatter = 
    let r = RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa)
    r.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1") |> ignore
    r
  let sha1 = 
    let crytProv = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
    crytProv.Initialize()
    crytProv

  let encrypt (data: byte[]) = 
    let hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data)
    rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(hash)

  let verify (data: byte[]) (signature: byte[]) = 
    let hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data)
    rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signature)
```

The `encrypt` & `verify` method is used like so

```ml
let signature = GenericCryptography.encrypt (message |> Helpers.getUTF8Bytes)
let encryptedMessage = GenericCryptography.encrypt (message |> Helpers.getUTF8Bytes)
let verifiedSignature = GenericCryptography.verify encryptedMessage signature
```

This fails with

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Key does not exist.

This isn't mentioned in the docs for verifying... I'm not sure why I'm getting that - I know I import the public key, and has something to do with that, but what is the question

---

To repro, just do `var rsa = RSA.Create()` and do `rsa.ExportParameters(false)`, this will return you a structure where you can get the `Modulus` and `Exponent` from to pass to the `createRsa` function

---

### Further Analysis

This happens on this line:

```ml
let encrypt (data: byte[]) = 
  let hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data)
  rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(hash) //<-- this line
```

Comment: I am not familiar with F#, but there seems to be no difference between `signature` and `encryptedMessage`. I would expect that in the `verify()` method `message` (and not `encryptedMessage`) is verified with `signature`.

Comment: you know what that looks like a valid spot there - let me adjust and see what happens

Comment: @Topaco I've update the question with some further analysis

Comment: You import only the modulus and public exponent, i.e. you create a _public_ key. For the signature, however, the _private_ key is needed (the public key is needed for verification). I.e. you have to import additionally `D`, `P`, `Q`, `DP`, `DQ` and `InverseQ` (alternatively you can use the original `RSA.Create()` directly). If you are trying to import a private key, there might be a simpler solution: .NET5 supports the import of different formats, e.g. `RSA.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey()` for PKCS8 or `RSA.ImportRSAPrivateKey()` for PKCS1.

Comment: Ideally I was going for, a central authority gives you a public key, you use that and a custom private key to sign data, then when given to another service, they use that central authority public key to verify the data

Comment: You are more or less directly describing a PKI there. You probably need X.509 certificates  and - probably - CMS messaging. Both are provided in the standard libs And stay away from SHA-1 *especially* when it comes to signature generation.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes of course, not using SHA-1, just trying to test it out

Comment: @MaartenBodewes have you got links to .NET 5 guides for CMS messaging and X509?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as stated in the comments, is that when importing the RSA Parameters, only the public key was set, and in order encrypt it would need private key as well.